# Mapbox RMTileCacheBackgroundDelegate callbacks not working

Tags: ios, swift, mapbox

I have the swift code below. Everything on the map is working as-expected, but I never see any of the RMTileCashBackgroundDelegate methods being called. All I see is "Caching started!" and then nothing. I've tried lots of tweaks but can't get this working. Any help would be much appreciated!

```
class MapboxViewController: UIViewController, RMMapViewDelegate, RMTileCacheBackgroundDelegate {
    var mapView: RMMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let mapSource:RMMapboxSource = RMMapboxSource(mapID: "myMapId")

        mapView = RMMapView(frame: self.view.bounds, andTilesource: mapSource)
        mapView.delegate = self

        //background caching
        mapView.tileCache.backgroundCacheDelegate = self
        mapView.tileCache.beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource(mapView.tileSource, southWest: swBounds, northEast: neBounds, minZoom: 13, maxZoom: 17)
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        mainView.addSubview(mapView)
    }

    func tileCache(tileCache: RMTileCache!, didBeginBackgroundCacheWithCount tileCount: Int, forTileSource tileSource: RMTileSource) {
        println("Caching started!")
    }
    func tileCache(tileCache: RMTileCache!, didBackgroundCacheTile tile: RMTile, withIndex tileIndex: Int, ofTotalTileCount totalTileCount: Int) {
        println("Cached tile \(tileIndex) of \(totalTileCount)")
    }
    func tileCache(tileCache: RMTileCache!, didReceiveError error: NSError!, whenCachingTile tile: RMTile) {
        println("Error caching tile")
    }
    func tileCacheDidCancelBackgroundCache(tileCache: RMTileCache!) {
        println("Caching cancelled!")
    }
    func tileCacheDidFinishBackgroundCache(tileCache: RMTileCache!) {
        println("Caching complete!")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two issues here, one that isn't obvious in the code above:

1. the tileCache functions take UInt rather than Int (forced once I upgraded to Swift 1.2)
2. My bounding box in beginBackgroundCacheForTileSource was being rounded such that I ended up with a bounding *line* with no tiles. This was sloppy on my part and actually led to a crash with the Mapbox iOS SDK.

Thanks to Mapbox support for their help. Here is a nice offline cache example in Swift for reference: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk-offline